# Android - setText before changing displayed child with ViewFlipper

Tags: android, textview, viewflipper

I'm trying to change text with `TextView.setText` but it updates after I change `ViewFlipper` displayed child with `setDisplayedChild`. I also tried calling invalidate but it doesn't work, text is changing after view is displayed (invalidate doesn't have to be called immediately).

Code:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.summary);
text.setText( /* text here */ );
flipper.setDisplayedChild(NUMBER);
```

I believe these all is called on UI thread.

How can I fix this?

Comment: post relevant code so that we can help.

Comment: Is the textview inside one of the views of the view flipper?

Answer (score 0):

I have fount the solution. Put your textview in another container.like this

And in Oncreate Mehtod

```
newsFeedTextView.setSelected(true);
```

It will defiantly work.enjoy

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/newsLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newsFeedTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/splash_bg"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Manchester United boss David Moyes is from the Champions League."
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
      </LinearLayout>
```